# Display values of product attributes available in stock on the WooCommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I'm using code that shows the product attribute on the shop page.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_loop_product_meta', 50 );
function custom_loop_product_meta() {
    global $product;
    
    if( ! is_object( $product ) ) { 
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    } 
    
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        
        echo '<div class="pa-block">';
        echo esc_html( pll__( 'Sizes' ) );
        echo '<span class="pa-block-text">: ' . $product->get_attribute('pa_size') . '</span>';
        echo '</div>';
    
    }

}
```

Now the product shows all values of the attribute "Size". How can I show the attribute values of products that are available (quantity greater than 1) and hide the attribute values (quantity equal to 0)?

For example, a variable product has sizes - 116 (0 pcs.), 122 (0 pcs.), 128 (1 pcs.). Only one size is available - 128 (1 piece), which should be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display specific attribute term names for a variable product from in stock variations only, use the following:

```php
// Utility function: Lightweight SQL query to get instock attribute term names
function get_instock_attribute_term_names( $product_id, $taxonomy ) {
    global $wpdb; 
    return $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT DISTINCT t.name FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p 
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id 
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.post_id 
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms t ON pm2.meta_value = t.slug
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'product_variation' AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND p.post_parent = %d AND pm2.meta_key = '%s'
        AND pm.meta_key = '_stock' AND pm.meta_value > 0 
        AND tt.taxonomy = '%s'
    ", $product_id, 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, $taxonomy ) );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_loop_product_meta', 50 );
function custom_loop_product_meta() {
    global $product;
    
    if( ! is_object( $product ) ) { 
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    } 
    
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        $taxonomy   = 'pa_size';
        $term_names =  get_instock_attribute_term_names( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy );

        if ( ! empty($term_names) ) {
            printf( '<div class="pa-block">%s:<span class="pa-block-text"> %s</span></div>', 
            esc_html( pll__( 'Sizes' ) ), implode(', ', $term_names) );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). tested and works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Everything works perfectly.